# how to execute multiple applications(jars) in spark simultaneously?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

When I try to submit more than 1 jar only 1 starts processing and others remain in waiting state. This happens because all the workers are allocated to the first application.

And the available setting (spark.cores.max) is to limit number of cores for a jar/application, but not the number of workers/executors.

So what happens is, if I create 8 workers with 4 cores each i.e. total 32 cores.

If the property spark.cores.max is set to 10 cores for my application it uses all the 8 workers with 10 cores i.e. 1 core on 6 workers and 2 cores on 2 workers, or some similar setting but all workers. 
And when I submit another jar it stays in waiting state till the running application ends.

As of now I am creating 1 worker per core i.e. 32 workers which is odd.

So is there a way to deal with this situation in spark, since because of this my executors are not working properly and after some time stops working for some unknown reason or I start getting OOM exception.

Comment: Can you add how you are launching your applications? If you are running them on Mesos or Yarn or local?

Comment: I'm running it in standalone mode.

Comment: And? What about the other question?

Comment: I'm running it in standalone mode (no Mesos, no Yarn) and submitting the jar using spark-submit.

Comment: please @SorabhKumar write down your spark-submit, so that people can actually try to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `--num-executors` parameter instead. Bear in mind, that if, for example, you're submitting your job to the YARN in cluster mode, one worker is required for the application driver, so your application will consume one more worker than you've specified in `--num-executors`.

Comment: I'm running it in standalone mode, however this solution is not working, what it does is it uses all workers with less number of cores.